# What is the determinant of the matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-exponential

If M be a $2\times2$ matrix such that $$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}&0 \end{bmatrix}$$ then what is the determinant of $e^M$. I think first to calculate $e^M$ then find out the determinant. Am I correct? Pls answer me in detail.

Comment: If you write $M=A^{-1}DA$ with $D$ diagonal, then $e^M=A^{-1}e^DA$ and $e^D$ is a diagonal matrix with the emponential of the elements of the diagonal of $D$ in its diagonal. For this matrix [it is possible to get such factorization](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+form+%5B%5B1,(1-i)%2Fsqrt(2)%5D,%5B(1%2Bi)%2Fsqrt(2),0%5D%5D)

Comment: $\det(e^A) = e^{{\rm tr}(A)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon diagonalization of $$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

We get $M=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is  a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are eigenvalues of $M.$

$$ \det (exp (M)) = \det ( exp (D)) =e^{\lambda _1 + \lambda_2}= e^{tr D}=e^{tr M} =e$$

Answer (score 4):

No need:$$\det\bigl(\exp(M)\bigr)=\exp(\operatorname{tr}M)=e^1=e.$$